# RestTemplate: Custom Exception thrown from ResponseErrorHandler is NOT Propagating to Caller

Tags: java, spring, exception, resttemplate

I am developing an API. Going by [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) and other clean programming guidelines, I **do not want to clutter my code with try/catch blocks**. However I am facing a challenge: a custom Exception thrown from ResponseErrorHandler is not propagating to the caller; instead it is ResourceAccessException that the caller receives.

Here is my API code (irreverent part is omitted for brevity). Note I am not surrounding restTemplate.delete() call in a try block - that is intentional:

```
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(ecmResponseErrorHandler);
restTemplate.delete(serviceUrl, params);
```

My ecmResponseErrorHandler code (irreverent part is omitted for brevity):

```
public class ECMResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
            //logging etc.
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
       //appropriately populate ECMException() and then throw it
       throw new ECMException();
    }
}
```

My ECMException is (irreverent part is omitted for brevity):

```
public class ECMException extends IOException {

    public ECMException() {
        super();
    }
    //etc.

 }
```

Now, instead of receiving ECMException, my JUnit test case receives ResourceAccessException:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.db.dbbpm.ecmfacade.exception.ECMException> but was<org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException>
```

Everything works fine if I change my API code to below; however I don't want to clutter my API code with try/catch blocks:

```
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(ecmResponseErrorHandler);
try {
    restTemplate.delete(serviceUrl, params);
} catch () {
    throw new ECMException();
}
```

**Why is the ECMException thrown from ResponseErrorHandler not propagating up all the way to caller? How do I make it happen?**

Comment: Because ResponseErrorHandler  only handles calls with responses, if can't connect then ResourceAccessException thrown from some other spring code, and it doesn't use ResponseErrorHandler at all.

Comment: By the way, clean code also says to do not use encoded namings... what the hell is ECMException? :)

Comment: @DanielHári: In my domain you hear ECM more often than even HTTP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management I agree that the question and answer would be more readable with `ECM` replaced with `My`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making ECMException extend RuntimeException (instead of IOException) solved the problem. Now my code is much cleaner.

```
public class ECMException extends RuntimeException {

    public ECMException() {
        super();
    }
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: After mulling over it a couple days, I decided that I am not going to throw any custom exception. It does not add any value to create a custom exception for the sake of it; instead I am throwing the exception I receive from the `RestTemplate` call; e.g. `HttpClientErrorException`. I think there is no need to create a custom exception because the caller of my APIs will have to know about a new custom exception whereas the exceptions like `HttpClientErrorException` are more 'known' and meaningful.

Comment: I am in the same boot, I want to wrap errors to a custom exception hierarchy specific for a rest endpoint. I think it's a good idea at the client code to deal with exact exceptions and forget about response statuses.